# Why I get The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection error?

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm beginner in oracle,want to use the oracle database in my windows application,

But when I run the project i get this error:

> The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'
>   threw an exception.

in this line of code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't complete.Maybe You don't install Oracle client on your system or you can change your project to x86 or maybe is for dll version.
You should notice to inner exception.

Comment: Thanks,mersi shahrooz