# Oracle connection fails

Tags: oracle, exception, connection

My Oracle connection is failing.  I get:

> SqlCommand Failed due to: The type initializer for
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.

Inner exception is:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Any thoughts?

Code:

```
try
                {
                    var connectionString = OracleSqlUtils.CreateConnectionString(credential.Value, ssisPackage: false);
                    using (var sqlConnection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            sqlConnection.Open();
                        }

                        using (var sqlCommand = new OracleCommand(context.ReplacementPlaceholders(this.Command), sqlConnection))
                        {
                            object sqlResult;
                            // Set command Timeout
                            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = timeout;
                            // Adds all the parameter
                            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                            {

                                if (parameter.ParameterName == "@JobID")
                                {
                                    var a = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@JobID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                                    a.SqlValue = parameter.Value.ToString();
                                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(a);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                                }
                            }

                            this.LocalLogger(TraceLevel.Verbose, "Start SqlCommand: {0}", sqlCommand.CommandText);
                            switch (this.CommandType)
                            {
                                case "XmlReader":
                                    sqlResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();
                                    break;
                                case "NonQuery":
                                    sqlResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    break;
                                case "Reader":
                                    sqlResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                                    break;
                                //case "Scalar":
                                default:
                                    sqlResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                                    break;
                            }
                            result = SqlCommandValidation(context, sqlResult);
                        }


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.LocalTracker(ExecutionMessageType.Error, "SqlCommand Failed due to: {0}", ex.Message);
                    this.LocalLogger(TraceLevel.Error, "stackTrace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
                    context.JobResultStatus = JobResultStatus.Fail;
                }
```

Oracle Connection String used:

Data Source=XXXXPRD;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXX;

Comment: The prefix is just from my own catch logic.

Comment: Updated with the code triggering the error

Comment: Now it's the `SqlParameter` you're adding instead of `OracleParameter` that catch my eye but I would expect the exception to be thrown by the initialization inside the `using()` so your connection string must be off somehow. Can you please add an example (with your sensitive information replaced) of the connection string returned from `OracleSqlUtils.CreateConnectionString`?

Comment: I added the connection string

Comment: See [Why I get The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33361664/205233) and [The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/914291/205233) for others experiencing the same issue. I'd put my bet on x64 vs. 32bit after seeing those.